# couchdb erlang reduce - aggregate object

Tags: object, view, erlang, couchdb, reduce

Say I have a map that emits the following objects

```
{"basePoints": 2000, "bonusPoints": 1000}
{"basePoints": 1000, "bonusPoints": 50}
{"basePoints": 10000, "bonusPoints": 5000}
```

How could I write a reduce in Erlang (not javascript) that would return an aggregate object like this:

```
{"basePoints": 13000, "bonusPoints": 6050}
```

(I would rather not have to write 2 separate views that emits each value separately if I can help it)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You actually do not need special reduce, in this case you can use standard `_sum`, since it’s able to sum not only numbers, but also arrays of numbers.

Just emit `[basePointsNum, 0]` for `basePoints` and `[0, bonusPointsNum]` for `bonusPoints`. Or if you have both fields in one doc you might emit `[basePointsNum, bonusPointsNum]`.

After reducing using built-in `_sum` you will receive an array of two numbers, each is a sum of appropriate index column. This feature seems to be undocumented, however works for both CouchDB and PouchDB, and it’s blazing fast.