# Sum two values in one view separately in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, view, mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

So Assume I have the following two documents in CouchDB:

```
{
   "_id": "197000000002",
   "_rev": "1-fbe819b01108f30d2e9e96f3fb46eff8",
   "iyear": "1970",
   "region_txt": "North America",
   "country": "130",
   "region": "1",
   "country_txt": "Mexico",
   "nkill": "1",
   "nwound": "1",

}

{
       "_id": "197000000003",
       "_rev": "1-fbe819b01108f30d2e9e96f3fb46eff8",
       "iyear": "1970",
       "region_txt": "North America",
       "country": "130",
       "region": "2",
       "country_txt": "Mexico",
       "nkill": "3",
       "nwound": "1"
    }
```

What I want is to SUM all the nkill and nwound values and have something like this:

```
[1970, "Mexico","North America"]    4, 2
```

At this moment I am only able to SUM one of the two values or both combined, but that is not what I want.

My Map Function now looks like this returned as result:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.nkill >= 1) {
        emit([doc.iyear,doc.country_txt,doc.region_txt],parseInt(doc.nkill));
    }
}
```

And I use **_sum** for the reduce function.

That returns me a key and value like this:

```
[1970, "Mexico", "North America"]   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom `reduce` function instead of CouchDB's built-in `_sum`.

You may pass an array or object as the value in the `reduce` function, separately sum the two values, then output the new array/object.

So that the `reduce` function can consume an object (for example), the `map` function should be changed to something like:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.nkill >= 1) {
        emit([doc.iyear,doc.country_txt,doc.region_txt],
            {nkill: parseInt(doc.nkill), nwound: parseInt(doc.nwound));
    }
}
```

### A different way

After looking over the CouchDB docs, it appears that [the strong preference](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html#reduce-rereduce) is to return scalar values from the `reduce` function - *or* an array.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50865322/562978) covers your use case: how to separately sum two different values from the same query.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried the map function. It gives me the two values back. But now I have duplicate values and with the _sum values I could atleast sum them up together and group them. Now I don't know how I can do the same with the two values. Do you have any clue what I need to use at the reduce option?

Comment: See my update - there was another SO question that appears to handle your use case.